# How can I make a var equal Itself plus a bit?

Tags: jquery, html, variables, constants, var

I'm trying to make a variable equal itself plus one for a piece of code I'm writing, the code is supposed to make all of the selected work. I know that the custom function works because the colour of the text turns blue. I just can't figure out how to make the var be itself plus one.

```
        var pSize = 140;

$('table tr td p').css({
    fontSize: pSize + '%',
});



$.fn.dynIncP = function(){

    var pSize = pSize + 3;

    $(this).css({
        color: 'blue',
        fontSize: pSize.toString() + '%',
    });
};

$('.bigTest').on('click', function(){
    $('table tr td p').dynIncP();
});
```

also, should I use var, or const? I read on Stackoverflow that const is better than var because var is "outdated". Is this true?

Comment: if you want to use the global variable you made then you should remove `var` from `var pSize = pSize + 3;` so it is just `pSize = pSize + 3;`

Comment: Yep, what keja said. When you put var in front of pSize again, you are creating a new local variable instead of changing the value of the variable you declared at the top.

Comment: P.S: you don't need `.toString()` if you already concatenate with `"%"` **String** ;)

Comment: Change `var pSize = pSize + 3;` to `pSize += 3;`.

Comment: Thank you all! You were a great help! @keja

Comment: Thank you for explaining how it works! @PatMellon

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Cool, got it @PHPglue